# Find record with latest datetime

Tags: datetime, ms-access

I have tried out muliple solutions to get my query to work, but it puts out too many results each time. I get correct answers with only TagID and datetime, but when I add other fields the problems start. I want the query to return only the latest record for each TagID, complete with site, event and datetime.

My table looks like this:

```
TagID   | Site    | Event | DateTime  
Asset1  | Tokyo   | IN    | 01.01.14 22:30  
Asset2  | Tokyo   | OUT   | 01.01.14 22:35  
Asset3  | Bern    | IN    | 01.01.14 22:40  
Asset3  | Bern    | OUT   | 01.01.14 23:30  
Asset4  | London  | IN    | 31.01.14 22:30  
Asset2  | London  | IN    | 31.01.14 22:30  
Asset3  | Tokyo   | IN    | 31.01.14 22:30
```

Output should be:

```
TagID   | Site    | Event | DateTime  
Asset1  | Tokyo   | IN    | 01.01.14 22:30  
Asset4  | London  | IN    | 31.01.14 22:30  
Asset2  | London  | IN    | 31.01.14 22:30  
Asset3  | Tokyo   | IN    | 31.01.14 22:30
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to add a tag about which data technology you are working with. Is SQL involved?

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Comment: I am using MS Access SQL

Comment: If you paste what you have tried we could tell you what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this if you're working with SQL Server and/or Microsoft Access.

```
SELECT t.TagID, t.Site, t.Event, t.DateTime
FROM
(
  SELECT TagID, MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDateTime
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY TagID
) r
INNER JOIN Table t
ON r.TagID = t.TagID AND r.MaxDateTime = t.DateTime
```

Comment: I hav tried this out, but get a syntax error in the FROM-part. I have named my table t, and think i shold then be able to just paste the SQL right into my editor and get a result?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I got your table name right (is it really just `t`?), but you have to adjust the table name on line 5 and 8 from `Table` to whatever it is. I tested the query in Access 2013 on my machine and it worked.

Comment: Works great! Thank you for quick response. I have troubled over this for days.